# Draw heatmap with coordinates in city based on count in R

Tags: r, heatmap, ggmap

I have a csv file which consists of city,neighborhood names along with coordinates i.e. longitude,latitude and finally frequency(or count) of them.

What i want to do is to show specific locations based on their counts in R. 
For example if one neighborhood has 23946 value and second has 14092 value, first one would be more red.

Let's assume name of our table is neighborhoods.

[image: ![enter image description here]

OCR'd data (https://www.newocr.com/ worked surprisingly well with just a link to this screen capture):

```
Lat Lon Count
41.06643 29.01236 25748
40.97710 29.12442 23946
41.05807 29.00484 21482
40.96989 29.09168 20476
41.07210 29.00050 18780
41.06419 29.00197 18327
40.99711 29.10434 18190
40.98212 29.11201 18144
40.97716 29.06092 17585
40.95959 29.09477 17129
40.96848 29.08173 16775
41.06605 29.00755 16142
41.08079 29.02863 15872
```

So far, i've written these codes yet:

```
mapIstanbul <- get_map(location='Istanbul',zoom=12) # To create Istanbul map
```

**By the way, Lon is fourth column and Lat is third column. Name of fifth column is Count.**

```
ggmap(mapIstanbul, extent = "device") + geom_density2d(data = neighborhoods, 
aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, size = Count)) + stat_density2d(data = neighborhoods, 
aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..), size = 0.01, 
bins = 16, geom = "polygon") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high ="red", 
guide = FALSE) + scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.3), guide = FALSE)
```

But it plotted something like this. So, how can i plot the right heatmap which i want? Which parameters should i change?
[image]

Comment: A very similar case study is given in this `ggmap` paper: http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/kahle-wickham.pdf